# c# how to read xml attributes with xelement

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xelement

I have a XML with this string:

```
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tMQm4zsM-Yg/TdFEfG2y7GI/AAAAAAAAAT0/XGyQ8vFdVwY/s72-c/moorea-view.jpg" height="72" width="72" />
```

how can I read the attribute "url" with XElement?

Answer (score 18):

Use [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) method

```
yourxElement.Attribute("url").Value;
```